# Specific Word Count in office word docx files,Python Package

Tags: python, office, microsoft-word

What would be the best approach to count number of words in a microsoft word document in terms of attributes like font size or font color . Eg: Return number of words in red font. I can code that but basically I need a push in the right direction . Spent my entire day with ElementTree package,python  and realized it wasn't the best approach.

My first preference is any **python** package , so I'm looking forward for some suggestions.
win32com , elementtree , lxml were in my mind. Not sure yet.

Non pythonic approaches are also welcome.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you expect the Python package to do. On this site, we can help you find a package that accomplishes a particular task, but we can't help you write your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) it allows full manipulation of word docx files, including (according to the [quickstart](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart.html) guide), "open and work on an existing Word document".  *The documentation is a bit light on the fact that once you have opened an existing document the same semantics apply for existing elements as for elements you are adding*. This is made clearer [here](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/documents.html) where it says:

> python-docx allows you to create new documents as well as make changes
>   to existing ones. Actually, it only lets you make changes to existing
>   documents; it’s just that if you start with a document that doesn’t
>   have any content, it might feel at first like you’re creating one from
>   scratch.

You can then parse the paragraphs for [runs](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/text.html#run-objects) and the runs for the characteristics you are searching for and use the text attribute to get the matching [text](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.Run.text).

- Pythonic
- Free (Gratis & FLOSS)
- Don't need word installed (Win32/Com solutions do)
- Should work on Linux/Mac & Windows

To install just:

```
pip install python-docx
```

Comment: Are you sure it has the reading functions too? Going through the docs , I've noticed it just has writing functions. Please share any link that might have the answer.

Comment: @Swordy - The documentation is light on how to read documents - added so text and links to the answer above that should help.

Comment: Thanks , could you please also add any non pythonic approaches you know of because python-docx hasn't got many features to easily identify the complexity of microsoft word.

Answer (score 1):

For a non-Pythonic approach you could consider a couple of other possibilities using MS Word as a starting point.

1. You can use words find, click on the advanced tag and you can search for a given set of characteristics and use find all - the downside is that you need to know in advance which characteristics you are looking for.
2. You could export your document from word to a less complex format such as html and then use either python tools such as [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or regular expressions to parse the resulting html file.  This would probably be the quickest option to implement but does rely on having Word available.
3. You can use a recent version of [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/installing.html) to do the conversion above and then use BS to parse.

Comment: Maybe implementing something like exporting a word file to html in python itself and then use beautiful soup to extract it . Actually i wouldn't want a dependency on word so this seems legit.